# Ansible Idempotency

Tags: ansible

I am using this playbook to copy a tar file, the playbook runs well.

```
- name: Copy Tar File
  hosts: all
tasks:
  - name: "Copy tar file "
    copy:
     src: /home/example.tar 
     dest: /tmp/example.tar
    when: ansible_os_family == 'Redhat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '7'
 tags:
- Copy Tar File
```

To test the playbook again I remove the `tar` file on my target server and run the playbook again, this time the task is skipped and the tar file is not copied:

```
PLAY RECAP  ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Could someone explain to me how Ansible manages its cache and how to avoid this problem?

Comment: "skipped" is usually only used with a "when:" condition on the task. Is this the complete playbook? (also it is formatted incorrectly so I assume not)

Comment: I update the post , i put the complete playbook.
Effectively when i remove the when condition the playbook copy the file.
So how can i resolve this please ?

Comment: By "test the playbook" do you mean you're using the `--check` option?

Comment: No I run it again

Comment: The value of `ansible_os_family` on Red Hat systems is `RedHat`, not `Redhat`.

Comment: @mhutter , you put  `Redhat` twice , it's the same word .

Comment: @Med no, once `H` is uppercase, once `h` is lowercase.

Comment: @mhutter you resolve my issue, i never thought that lowercase would be do that. thank you

Comment: String comparisons are always case-sensitive :-)